# Add a synchronization secret with msgraph-beta-sdk-java

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to use msgraph-beta-sdk-java to add/setup a synchronization job to a service principal. I'm able to create a SynchronizationJob from the SynchronizationTemplate attached to the ServicePrincipal object, but I'm having trouble when trying to add the required SynchronizationSecret to it.

First, the validateCredentials function seems to be broken (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java/issues/372).

But my question here is about how to actually add those secrets to the ServicePrincipal as documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/synchronization-synchronization-secrets?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http? Is it simply missing from msgraph-beta-sdk-java?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi , why want to use beta? Any specific reason ? everything that is supported with beta SDK(Java) is here - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java .

Comment: Hi, I use beta because I need some MS Graph features that are only in MS Graph beta yet

Comment: have you looked into the docs , everything that is supported with beta SDK(Java) - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java

Comment: Yes I have looked into those docs, and I couldn't find in those docs how to add secrets to a ServicePrincipal.

Comment: Sorry for delayed response , If its not there in the doc then this is available for msgraph-beta-sdk-java in that case , if you want this to available , you can raise a feature request - https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message , thanks